# BigQuery - turn columns to array

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, nest

I have this table:

[image: current table]

I'm looking for this table:

[image: looking for this table]

I have searched for array functions (`array_agg`) and it didn't work as expected.

How can I approach this task? Would I have to loop into this column?

My dataset:

```
SELECT 1 id, 'protoc1' protoc UNION ALL
SELECT 2 id, 'protoc2' protoc UNION ALL
SELECT 3 id, 'protoc3' protoc
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below

```
select id, format('%t', array_agg(protoc) over()) protoc
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Mikhail, I really appreciate it, it worked, thanks so much and I will share this post to help that are passing thrugh similar tasks, thanks againg and I will keep on learning!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why you want that output, but I noticed you had the array repeated for all rows, and looked like you wanted the array represented as a specific string -- so here's my attempt at what you're asking:

```
with sample as (
  SELECT 1 id, 'protoc1' protoc UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, 'protoc2' protoc UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id, 'protoc3' protoc 
), formatted_string as (
  select "[" || ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(protoc),', ') || "]" as protoc
  from sample
)
select sample.id, formatted_string.protoc
from formatted_string
cross join sample
```

[image: Running match of requested output]

Comment: Mike, thanks so much for sharing your reasoning;, I didn't know about this approach, it also worked! thanks againg for your time and attention, have a good weekend!